# How to send email with attachment using cURL with Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, curl, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to build a simple Logic App in Azure, that sends an email with a zip attachment using cURL from a Linux VM.

In the Logic App, without the attachment it is working fine.
But it breaks once Attachment is configured.

JSON schema, When a HTTP request is received:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "Attachments": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "cc": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "from": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "html": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subject": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "to": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

[Config for Outlook Send an email v2, Logic App, Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UBHJ.png)

Commands to send email from Linux VM:

```
# create attachment
echo "abcd" > test.txt
zip test.zip test.txt

# curl to send json to azure logic app, with attachment
curl -vvv --request POST \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --url 'https://prod-21.southeastasia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxx/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=xxx' \
  --data '{"from": "xxx@outlook.com", "cc": "xxx@outlook.com, "Attachments": [{ "Content-Type": "BASE64_ENCODED_CONTENT", "Name": "test.zip" }], "to": "xxx@outlook.com", "subject": "Hello, World!", "html": "Hey, test email." }'
```

[Error message from the Run History, Logic App, Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQfpv.png)

Full error from the log:

```
{
      "status": 400,
      "message": "Parameter 'Attachment Content' cannot be null or empty.\r\nclientRequestId: 40d2dc9c-549b-4608-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "error": {
        "message": "Parameter 'Attachment Content' cannot be null or empty."
      },
      "source": "office365-sea.azconn-sea.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

Would like to know how to handle the attachment on this scenario. Any documentation would be helpful as well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Would be also interested in this topic!
Did you try to use --form instead of --data? Or do you already have a solution for this?

I also tried to specify the "Attachments" property in logic apps as:

```
    "properties": {
      "Attachment": {
          "contentEncoding": "base64",
          "contentMediaType": "image/png",
          "type": "string"
      },
    }
    ...
```